# Dynamically adding fields on HTML Form

Tags: jquery, html, multi-select, sumoselect.js

I am working on simple form where, user can input the text and assign tags to (optional) text, As user can select multiple tags i decided to use select tag with "multiple" attribute. All works as expected for first row, but as i move to add new element dynamically all multiple select box does not behave as 1st row.

1. I am using SumoSelect / BootStrap-Select JQuery plugins to make my multi select box look better (https://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/)
2. With bootstrap-select i manage to add another row and element on newly added row is working independently of row above but it adds 2 of such multi select boxes.
3. With SumoSelect, newly added multi select box is not responsive

*Its bit complicated to explain, so below is the code and screen shot*

**HTML Code:**

```
     <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="summary">
       <br>
       <a href="#">
            <span id="add_something" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" title="add summary" aria-hidden="true"></span>
       </a>
       <br><br>
       <div id="something_tbl">
           <p>Something <span class="user_info" style="padding-left: 5px; color:gray;">Enter something...</span></p>
           <p>
               <ol>
                    <li style="padding-bottom: 5px;" id="something_pt">
                        <input type="text" style="width: 70%;" placeholder="enter something" id="something" name="something">
                        <select name="something_tags" multiple size="5"
                                id="lbl_picker" class="selectpicker_1">
                            <option value="1">fun</option>
                            <option value="2">boring</option>
                            <option value="3">hehe</option>
                            <option value="4">lol</option>
                            <option value="5">xyz</option>
                        </select>
                    </li>
               </ol>
           </p>
       </div>
```

**JQuery/JavaScript:**

```
$("#add_something").on('click', function() {
  $('#something_tbl ol li#something_pt:first').clone().insertAfter('#something_tbl ol li#something_pt:last');
  $("#something_tbl ol li#something_pt:last #something").val('')
  var elem = $('#something_tbl ol li#something_pt:last');
  elem.append('<a href=\"#\"><span id=\"remove_summary\" title=\"Remove\" class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-minus\" style=\"padding-left: 5px;\"></span></a>');
  add_lbl_picker();
  elem.children('a').click(remove_summary);
  return false;
});    

var remove_summary = function() {
    var tbl_length = $('#something_tbl ol li#summary_pt').length;
    if (tbl_length > 1) {
        $(this).parents('li').remove();
    }
    return false;
};

var add_lbl_picker = function() {
    var summary_tbl_length = $('#something_tbl ol li#something_point').length;
    $('#something_tbl ol li#something_point:last select#lbl_picker').attr("class", "selectpicker_" + summary_tbl_length);
    $('.selectpicker_' + summary_tbl_length).SumoSelect();
};

$('.selectpicker_1').SumoSelect();
```

**Image:**

[image: Multi Select not working]

As you can see above, what ever is selected in first "multi select" is copied to all rows and except for the 1st row all other multi select do not work!

Note: There will be maximum 5 values in multi select not more and values are statically loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is some confusion in your code for the correct utilisation of attributes "class" and "id". 
For your script, the code below does the job :

```
<div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="summary">
       <br>
       <a href="#">
            <span id="add_something" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" title="add summary" aria-hidden="true">lkjlkjk</span>
       </a>
       <br><br>
       <div id="something_tbl">
           <p>Something <span class="user_info" style="padding-left: 5px; color:gray;">Enter something...</span></p>
           <p>
               <ol>
                    <li style="padding-bottom: 5px;" class="something_pt">
                        <input type="text" style="width: 70%;" placeholder="enter something" class="something" name="something">
                        <select name="something_tags" multiple size="5" class="lbl_picker selectpicker_1">
                            <option value="1">fun</option>
                            <option value="2">boring</option>
                            <option value="3">hehe</option>
                            <option value="4">lol</option>
                            <option value="5">xyz</option>
                        </select>
                    </li>
               </ol>
           </p>
       </div>
    <script>
    $("#add_something").on('click', function() {    
        something_pt_content.clone().insertAfter('.something_pt:last');
        $('.remove_summary:last').click(function(){
            if ($('.something_pt').length > 1) {
                $(this).parents('li').remove();
            }   
        })
        $('.selectpicker_1').SumoSelect();
    });    
    var something_pt_content = $('.something_pt').clone().append('<a href=\"#\"><span title=\"Remove\" class=\"remove_summary glyphicon glyphicon-minus\" style=\"padding-left: 5px;\">oijojoj</span></a>');
    $('.selectpicker_1').SumoSelect();  
    </script>
```

Comment: I tried the above code but its not working as expected, could you try it on jfiddle and share it here (i know its not fair to ask you spend your time to set it on jfiddle but if it is possible for you to spend that much time), mean while i will be keep on trying :)

Answer (score 1):

I think where you wrote:

```
var add_lbl_picker = function() {
    var summary_tbl_length = $('#something_tbl ol li#something_point').length;
    $('#something_tbl ol li#something_point:last select#lbl_picker').attr("class", "selectpicker_" + summary_tbl_length);
    $('.selectpicker_' + summary_tbl_length).SumoSelect();
};
```

You really meant:

```
var add_lbl_picker = function() {
    var summary_tbl_length = $('#something_tbl ol li#something_pt').length;
    $('#something_tbl ol li#something_pt:last select#lbl_picker').attr("class", "selectpicker_" + summary_tbl_length);
    $('.selectpicker_' + summary_tbl_length).SumoSelect();
};
```

I changed ***something_point*** to ***something_pt***.

Comment: Thanks Filipe, that was just 1 place where i forgot to remove the actual field name. I have checked on my side and names are proper in html and JS.. but will keep on trying ..